# reportProgress is not working in production

Tags: angular, typescript, file-upload, progress-bar, production

When I'm uploading video file, it works normally on local (develop mode). But when i'm uploading it to the server (prod), it doesn't work.
Here is the service:

```
uploadVideo(id: String, file, imageId) {
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('video', file);
        formData.append('imageId', imageId);
        return this.http.post<any>(`.../${id}/video`, formData, {reportProgress: true, observe: 'events'})
                .pipe(map(response => {
                        return response;
                }));
    }
```

Here is the component ->

```
this.arrivalProductService.uploadVideo(this.data.id, this.selectedFile, imageId)
      .pipe(
        map((event) => {
          console.log('event', event);
          if(event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress){
            const percentDone = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
            return { status: 'progress', message: percentDone };
          }
          if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
            return event.body;
          }
        }),
        catchError(error => {
          return throwError(error);
        }),
        finalize(() => {
          console.log('completed');
        })
      )
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          ....
       })
```

If I'm logging event on map(), on local dev it return all progress: like ({status: 'progress', message: 0}, ... etc), on production it returns nothing.. 
I can't understand what's wrong with the code.. please help me

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215493/discussion-on-question-by-daniyar-reportprogress-is-not-working-in-production).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are probably using a service worker in your production build.

https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-devops#bypassing-the-service-worker

> Bypassing the service worker
>   In some cases, you may want to bypass the service worker entirely and let the browser handle the request instead. An example is when you rely on a feature that is currently not supported in service workers **(e.g. [reporting progress on uploaded files](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/1141))**.
>
> To bypass the service worker you can set ngsw-bypass as a request header, or as a query parameter. (The value of the header or query parameter is ignored and can be empty or omitted.)

so in your case:

```
uploadVideo(id: String, file, imageId) {
        let formData = new FormData();
        const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'ngsw-bypass': ''});

        formData.append('video', file);
        formData.append('imageId', imageId);
        return this.http.post<any>(`.../${id}/video`, formData, {reportProgress: true, observe: 'events', headers: headers})
                .pipe(map(response => {
                        return response;
                }));
}
```

Comment: When not using angular, add a condition to your serviceworker's fetch e.g. `self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => { if (event.request.method != 'GET') return; /*event.respondWith(...your regular code*/ });`