# angular reportProgress always only get the type of upload complete

Tags: angular

I'm using angular 14 and I'm using an upload service, I want to get a progress feedback, the code is below, but it doesn't seem to work

> repo https://github.com/rick-chou/angular-tutorial/blob/issue_reportProgress/src/views/basic-syntax/http/http.service.ts

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '@env';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class HttpService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public uploadFile(formData: FormData, type: 'single' | 'multiple' = 'single') {
    return this.http.put(`${environment.backend}/file-upload/${type}`, formData, {
      reportProgress: true,
      observe: 'events',
    });
  }
}
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpService } from './http.service';
import { NzCardModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/card';
import { NzButtonModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/button';
import { NzUploadFile, NzUploadModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/upload';

@Component({
  selector: 'http',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [NzCardModule, NzUploadModule, NzButtonModule],
  templateUrl: './http.component.html',
})
export class HttpComponent implements OnInit {
  public fileList: NzUploadFile[] = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpService) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {}

  public handleUpload = (file: NzUploadFile, fileList: NzUploadFile[]) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file as unknown as File);
    this.http.uploadFile(formData).subscribe((event) => {
      console.log(event);
    });
    return false;
  };
}
```

I always only get the type of upload complete

[image]

Comment: how big is the file you are trying to send? Can you check your network tab regarding how long the request took?

Comment: yes I tried with a large file and set slow 3G,  but it still doesn't seem to work, I can only get the type 4

Comment: how many ms did your upload take (as seen in the network tab)?

Comment: 14s .  I implemented it with XMLHttpRequest but I want to know why it doesn't work in angular

Comment: Are you using a service worker? Maybe this could be the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62257571/8148929

Comment: thx famenev! I tried your method but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: and I checked the developer tools and I confirmed that I don't have service worker enabled